Appimages is not working in Ubuntu 24.04
The application Enigma Messenger chat app for Linux is used. It comes in the format app.image, but in the previous Ubuntu 22.04 it worked. I've already updated it, the libfuse and libfuse2 repositories are already there.
website

What Error do you get when you try to run the app?  We need more than it worked in a previous version.  Try running the app in a terminal window, and paste what the terminal displays, and post it here

This question is similar to: How to make Balena Etcher appimage work in Ubuntu 24.04?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
